# Academic experience VS Research experience

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *academic experience* and *research experience*?

In my opinion, *academic experience* is a super set of *research experience*. Is that right?

But, what other aspects should *academic experience* contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be some overlap between *academic experience* and *research experience* but in general they are distinct sets of experience.  One can be a *[researcher](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/researcher)* in academia, in private industry, independently, *etc.* without being an academic person; and one  can be an *[academic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/academic#Noun)* without being involved in research.  (At colleges or universities that are also *[research institutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_institution)*, many faculty will accrue academic and research experience simultaneously, by both teaching and doing research.)

Thus, neither is a superset or subset of the other.

Teaching is the principal component of academic experience, but serving on faculty committees, advising students, grading papers and projects, *etc.* are part of it too.

*Edit:* As suggested by a comment, meaning of terms can depend on context.  It seems more proper to term "experience gained through coursework" as *education* or *educational experience*, or perhaps *academic background* instead of *academic experience*.  However, I don't know definitive category names or boundaries.  For example, some *vita* list degree work in the same section as academic positions held.  Two examples below are from Wikipedia page sections labeled **Academic Experience**.  The first example has snippets from a [Benjamin Sovacool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_K._Sovacool#Academic_experience) page; the second, from a [Jerry Linenger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_M._Linenger#Academic_experience) page.

> Sovacool is a Visiting Associate Professor at Vermont Law School and [...] was previously assistant professor at the Lee Kuan Yew School of Public Policy [... and] has a PhD in Science and Technology Studies from Virginia Tech.
>
> Linenger graduated from the U.S. Naval Academy and proceeded directly to medical school. [...] served as a naval flight surgeon [...]  doctorate-level training in epidemiology [...] research principal investigator at the Naval Health Research Center. He concurrently served as a faculty member at [UCSD]

Comment: I think that in a literal sense, academic experience IS a superset of research experience, since research is an academic pursuit. However, when an application asks you for academic experience, they mean something like "experience gained through coursework at a college/university/highschool".

For instance, suppose I'm a pre-med student and I've worked in a lab at the National Institutes of Health; that counts as "research experience", NOT academic experience.

Comment: @alcas  Agreed.  I've edited the answer, although not directly addressing your comment.